# Creating a NuGet package for Windows 7.1 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, jenkins, nuget

I've been creating NuGet packages for some of my libraries. The goal is to have my Jenkins build server use a CoApp .autopkg script to build a NuGet package that I can then use in other projects.

The issue is that the build server uses the standalone Windows 7.1 SDK rather than Visual Studio 2010.  I guess this is a separate Platform Toolset? So essentially, I can't use the packages compiled by the build server in my Visual Studio 2010 projects?  Do people normally install a copy of Visual Studio on their build servers?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using nuget.exe pack to create packages? You shouldn't need visual studio to run nuget.exe.

Here is a link to nuget.exe pack command reference - http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command

Comment: I'm using CoApp to generate packages, and nuget.exe to restore them after checking out from source control.

The problem is, if I create NuGet packages with the Toolset set to "vs100", I can use them in my Visual Studio 2010 projects, but the build server won't link the libraries because "vs100" doesn't match the toolset of msbuild included with the Windows 7.1 SDK which is "windows7.1sdk".

Do I need to create two pivots in CoApp, one for each toolset? Are they really that different?  Otherwise, if I'm developing on 2010, does it mean my build server will need 2010?